# How do I center this long circuit?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, circuitikz

I am having difficulty centering this long circuit. I scaled it so it would not go off the page but I have been unable to find a way to center it. I tried adapting the solutions used in this related post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275884/how-to-center-a-circuitikz-figure) but was unsuccessful. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I would also welcome any suggestions in terms of improving how I coded the circuit.

`   %%Full circuit as of March 25,16

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[siunitx,american]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\tikzstyle{every path}=[line width=1.0pt,line cap=round,line join=round]
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\scalebox{0.5}{
\begin{circuitikz}
%Shortcuts for fast coordinate snapping
    \def\shx{(1,0)}
    \def\shxn{(-1,0)}
    \def\shy{(0,1)}
    \def\shyn{(0,-1)}
    \def\un{2}
    \def\unx{(2,0)}
    \def\unxn{(-2,0)}
    \def\uny{(0,2)}
    \def\unyn{(0,-2)}
    \def\va{(-20,2.5)}
    \def\vb{(-20,-1.5)}
\draw %low pass filter upper ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\va
    to[open,v_=-15$V$,o-o,color=green]++\unyn
        node[ground] {} %{GND}
\va
    to[vR,l=10<\kilo\ohm>]++\unx
    --++(5,0)
        node[above] {$V$= -4$V$}
    --++\unyn
    to[R,l=10<\kilo\ohm>]++\unx coordinate (A)% creates an on the fly reference point for later
;

\draw % low pass filter lower ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\vb
    to[sqV,color=green,l_=PWM 0 $to$ 100\%,o-]++\unx
    to[R,l=10<\kilo\ohm>]++\unx coordinate(N2)
    to[C,l_=10<\micro\farad>]++(0,-1.5)
        node[ground] {} %{GND}
;

\draw %uniter gain buffer lower ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\vb++(6,-0.5)
    node [op amp,yscale=-1] (opamp) {}
    node {741}
(opamp.+)
    node[ above ] {3}
(opamp.-)
    node[ above ] {2}
(opamp.up)
    node[ below right ] {7}
    to [ short, -o ] ++(0,-0.5)
    node[below] {+15$V$}
(opamp.down)
    node[ above right ] {4}
    to [ short, -o ]++(0,0.5)
    node[above] {-15$V$}
(opamp.out)
    node[ right ] {6}
(opamp.+)
    to[short](N2)
(opamp.-)
    |-++\shyn
    to[short]++\unx
    -|(opamp.out)
    to[short]++(0,1.5)
    to[R,l=10<\kilo\ohm>]++\unx coordinate (B)% creates an on the fly reference point for later

;
\draw %V1 resistor  attached to difference --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(A)++\unx++(0,-0.5)% uses the reference here
    node [op amp] (opamp) {}
    node {741}
(opamp.+)
    node[ above ] {3}
(opamp.-)
    node[ above ] {2}
(opamp.up)
    node[ above right ] {7}
    to [ short, -o ] ++(0,0.5)
    node[above] {+15$V$}
(opamp.down)
    node[ below right ] {4}
    to [ short, -o ]++(0,-0.5)
    node[below] {-15$V$}
(opamp.out)
    node[ right ] {6}

(opamp.-)
    to[short](A)
    |-++(0,1.5)
    to[R,l=10<\kilo\ohm>]++\unx
    -|(opamp.out) coordinate (vbt)
    to[short]++(0,-1)
    to[short]++(1,0) coordinate (ProbeVbt) %probe point for branching of two probes
    to[short]++(1.5,0) coordinate(PhotoDiode+)
(opamp.+)
    to[short](B)
    to[R,l=10<\kilo\ohm>]++\unyn
        node[ground] {} %{GND}
;
\draw % VBT probing node structure ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(ProbeVbt)
    node[ below ] {$V_{B}$}
    to[short]++(0,7) coordinate (VBTProbeTop)
    to[R,l=1<\kilo\ohm>]++\unxn
++\unyn
    node[ground] {} %{GND}
    to[D*,l=$1N4148$]++\uny

(VBTProbeTop)++\unxn
    --++\unxn
    to[open,v_=$V_{B_{1}}$,o-o,color=red]++\unyn
        node[ground] {} %{GND}
;
\draw %Inverting unity and current safety for VB's -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(VBTProbeTop)++(2,-0.5)
    node [op amp] (opamp) {}
    node {741}
(opamp.+)
    node[ above ] {3}
(opamp.-)
    node[ below ] {2}
(opamp.up)
    node[ above right ] {7}
    to [ short, -o ] ++(0,0.5)
    node[above] {+15$V$}
(opamp.down)
    node[ below right ] {4}
    to [ short, -o ]++(0,-0.5)
    node[below] {-15$V$}
(opamp.out)
    node[ below ] {6}

(opamp.-)
    --(VBTProbeTop)
(opamp.-)
    |-++\shy
    to[short]++\unx
    -|(opamp.out)
(opamp.+)
    --++\shyn
        node[ground] {} %{GND}
(opamp.out)
    to[R,l=1   <\kilo\ohm>]++\unx coordinate(D)
    --++\shx
    to[open,v^=$V_{B_{2}}$,o-o,color=red]++\unyn
        node[ground] {} %{GND}
;
\draw %photodiode ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(PhotoDiode+)
    to[pD,mirror,l_=$D_{P}$]++\uny coordinate (PhotoDiode-)
;
\draw %current amplifier ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(vbt)++\unx++\unx++\shx
    node [op amp] (opamp) {}
    node {741}
(opamp.+)
    node[ left ] {3}
(opamp.-)
    node[ left ] {2}
(opamp.up)
    node[ above right ] {7}
    to [ short, -o ] ++(0,0.5)
    node[above] {+15$V$}
(opamp.down)
    node[ below right ] {4}
    to [ short, -o ]++(0,-0.5)
    node[below] {-15$V$}
(opamp.out)
    node[ below ] {6}

(opamp.+)
    to[short]++(0,-0.5) coordinate(C)
    to[short](PhotoDiode+)
(C)
    to[short]++\unyn
    to[R,l=650<\ohm>]++\unx
    to[vR,l=1<\kilo\ohm>]++\unyn
        node[ground] {}
(opamp.-)
    to[short]++(0,0.5) coordinate(D)
    to[short](PhotoDiode-)
(D)
    |-++\shy
    to[R,l=1.33<\kilo\ohm>]++\unx
    -|(opamp.out) coordinate (vc)
;

\draw % VIT probing node structure ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(vc)
    --++(7,0) coordinate (VITProbeBottom)
(VITProbeBottom)
    node[ below ] {$V_{I}$}
    to[short]++(0,5.5) coordinate (VITProbeTop)
    to[R,l=1<\kilo\ohm>]++\unxn
++\unyn
    node[ground] {} %{GND}
    to[D*,l=$1N4148$]++\uny

(VITProbeTop)++\unxn
    --++\unxn
    to[open,v_=$V_{I_{1}}$,o-o,color=red]++\unyn
        node[ground] {} %{GND}
;
\draw %Inverting unity and current safety for Vi2 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(VITProbeTop)++(2,-0.5)
    node [op amp] (opamp) {}
    node {741}
(opamp.+)
    node[ above ] {3}
(opamp.-)
    node[ below ] {2}
(opamp.up)
    node[ above right ] {7}
    to [ short, -o ] ++(0,0.5)
    node[above] {+15$V$}
(opamp.down)
    node[ below right ] {4}
    to [ short, -o ]++(0,-0.5)
    node[below] {-15$V$}
(opamp.out)
    node[ below ] {6}

(opamp.-)
    --(VITProbeTop)
(opamp.-)
    |-++\shy
    to[short]++\unx
    -|(opamp.out)
(opamp.+)
    --++\shyn
        node[ground] {} %{GND}
(opamp.out)
    to[R,l=1   <\kilo\ohm>]++\unx coordinate(E)
    --++\shx
    to[open,v^=$V_{I_{2}}$,o-o,color=red]++\unyn
        node[ground] {} %{GND}
;

\end{circuitikz}
}
\caption{Photo Diode Circuit as of Mar 26,16}\label{DiodeC}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the circuit is too wide for the text block, even though it is not too wide for the paper. One option is to scale the circuit to fit the text block. Another is to use a package such as `changepage` to temporarily reduce the margins, widening the text block.

However, if you are sure the diagram fits and are prepared to check the output yourself to ensure nothing strange is happening, another option is to simply lie to LaTeX about the width of the circuit. If we tell LaTeX that the circuit is `0pt` wide then it will be centred correctly:

[image: centred circuit]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[siunitx,american]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\tikzstyle{every path}=[line width=1.0pt,line cap=round,line join=round]
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\makebox[0pt]{%
\scalebox{0.5}{%
\begin{circuitikz}
%Shortcuts for fast coordinate snapping
    \def\shx{(1,0)}
    \def\shxn{(-1,0)}
    \def\shy{(0,1)}
    \def\shyn{(0,-1)}
    \def\un{2}
    \def\unx{(2,0)}
    \def\unxn{(-2,0)}
    \def\uny{(0,2)}
    \def\unyn{(0,-2)}
    \def\va{(-20,2.5)}
    \def\vb{(-20,-1.5)}
\draw %low pass filter upper ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\va
    to[open,v_=-15$V$,o-o,color=green]++\unyn
        node[ground] {} %{GND}
\va
    to[vR,l=10<\kilo\ohm>]++\unx
    --++(5,0)
        node[above] {$V$= -4$V$}
    --++\unyn
    to[R,l=10<\kilo\ohm>]++\unx coordinate (A)% creates an on the fly reference point for later
;

\draw % low pass filter lower ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\vb
    to[sqV,color=green,l_=PWM 0 $to$ 100\%,o-]++\unx
    to[R,l=10<\kilo\ohm>]++\unx coordinate(N2)
    to[C,l_=10<\micro\farad>]++(0,-1.5)
        node[ground] {} %{GND}
;

\draw %uniter gain buffer lower ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\vb++(6,-0.5)
    node [op amp,yscale=-1] (opamp) {}
    node {741}
(opamp.+)
    node[ above ] {3}
(opamp.-)
    node[ above ] {2}
(opamp.up)
    node[ below right ] {7}
    to [ short, -o ] ++(0,-0.5)
    node[below] {+15$V$}
(opamp.down)
    node[ above right ] {4}
    to [ short, -o ]++(0,0.5)
    node[above] {-15$V$}
(opamp.out)
    node[ right ] {6}
(opamp.+)
    to[short](N2)
(opamp.-)
    |-++\shyn
    to[short]++\unx
    -|(opamp.out)
    to[short]++(0,1.5)
    to[R,l=10<\kilo\ohm>]++\unx coordinate (B)% creates an on the fly reference point for later

;
\draw %V1 resistor  attached to difference --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(A)++\unx++(0,-0.5)% uses the reference here
    node [op amp] (opamp) {}
    node {741}
(opamp.+)
    node[ above ] {3}
(opamp.-)
    node[ above ] {2}
(opamp.up)
    node[ above right ] {7}
    to [ short, -o ] ++(0,0.5)
    node[above] {+15$V$}
(opamp.down)
    node[ below right ] {4}
    to [ short, -o ]++(0,-0.5)
    node[below] {-15$V$}
(opamp.out)
    node[ right ] {6}

(opamp.-)
    to[short](A)
    |-++(0,1.5)
    to[R,l=10<\kilo\ohm>]++\unx
    -|(opamp.out) coordinate (vbt)
    to[short]++(0,-1)
    to[short]++(1,0) coordinate (ProbeVbt) %probe point for branching of two probes
    to[short]++(1.5,0) coordinate(PhotoDiode+)
(opamp.+)
    to[short](B)
    to[R,l=10<\kilo\ohm>]++\unyn
        node[ground] {} %{GND}
;
\draw % VBT probing node structure ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(ProbeVbt)
    node[ below ] {$V_{B}$}
    to[short]++(0,7) coordinate (VBTProbeTop)
    to[R,l=1<\kilo\ohm>]++\unxn
++\unyn
    node[ground] {} %{GND}
    to[D*,l=$1N4148$]++\uny

(VBTProbeTop)++\unxn
    --++\unxn
    to[open,v_=$V_{B_{1}}$,o-o,color=red]++\unyn
        node[ground] {} %{GND}
;
\draw %Inverting unity and current safety for VB's -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(VBTProbeTop)++(2,-0.5)
    node [op amp] (opamp) {}
    node {741}
(opamp.+)
    node[ above ] {3}
(opamp.-)
    node[ below ] {2}
(opamp.up)
    node[ above right ] {7}
    to [ short, -o ] ++(0,0.5)
    node[above] {+15$V$}
(opamp.down)
    node[ below right ] {4}
    to [ short, -o ]++(0,-0.5)
    node[below] {-15$V$}
(opamp.out)
    node[ below ] {6}

(opamp.-)
    --(VBTProbeTop)
(opamp.-)
    |-++\shy
    to[short]++\unx
    -|(opamp.out)
(opamp.+)
    --++\shyn
        node[ground] {} %{GND}
(opamp.out)
    to[R,l=1   <\kilo\ohm>]++\unx coordinate(D)
    --++\shx
    to[open,v^=$V_{B_{2}}$,o-o,color=red]++\unyn
        node[ground] {} %{GND}
;
\draw %photodiode ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(PhotoDiode+)
    to[pD,mirror,l_=$D_{P}$]++\uny coordinate (PhotoDiode-)
;
\draw %current amplifier ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(vbt)++\unx++\unx++\shx
    node [op amp] (opamp) {}
    node {741}
(opamp.+)
    node[ left ] {3}
(opamp.-)
    node[ left ] {2}
(opamp.up)
    node[ above right ] {7}
    to [ short, -o ] ++(0,0.5)
    node[above] {+15$V$}
(opamp.down)
    node[ below right ] {4}
    to [ short, -o ]++(0,-0.5)
    node[below] {-15$V$}
(opamp.out)
    node[ below ] {6}

(opamp.+)
    to[short]++(0,-0.5) coordinate(C)
    to[short](PhotoDiode+)
(C)
    to[short]++\unyn
    to[R,l=650<\ohm>]++\unx
    to[vR,l=1<\kilo\ohm>]++\unyn
        node[ground] {}
(opamp.-)
    to[short]++(0,0.5) coordinate(D)
    to[short](PhotoDiode-)
(D)
    |-++\shy
    to[R,l=1.33<\kilo\ohm>]++\unx
    -|(opamp.out) coordinate (vc)
;

\draw % VIT probing node structure ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(vc)
    --++(7,0) coordinate (VITProbeBottom)
(VITProbeBottom)
    node[ below ] {$V_{I}$}
    to[short]++(0,5.5) coordinate (VITProbeTop)
    to[R,l=1<\kilo\ohm>]++\unxn
++\unyn
    node[ground] {} %{GND}
    to[D*,l=$1N4148$]++\uny

(VITProbeTop)++\unxn
    --++\unxn
    to[open,v_=$V_{I_{1}}$,o-o,color=red]++\unyn
        node[ground] {} %{GND}
;
\draw %Inverting unity and current safety for Vi2 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(VITProbeTop)++(2,-0.5)
    node [op amp] (opamp) {}
    node {741}
(opamp.+)
    node[ above ] {3}
(opamp.-)
    node[ below ] {2}
(opamp.up)
    node[ above right ] {7}
    to [ short, -o ] ++(0,0.5)
    node[above] {+15$V$}
(opamp.down)
    node[ below right ] {4}
    to [ short, -o ]++(0,-0.5)
    node[below] {-15$V$}
(opamp.out)
    node[ below ] {6}

(opamp.-)
    --(VITProbeTop)
(opamp.-)
    |-++\shy
    to[short]++\unx
    -|(opamp.out)
(opamp.+)
    --++\shyn
        node[ground] {} %{GND}
(opamp.out)
    to[R,l=1   <\kilo\ohm>]++\unx coordinate(E)
    --++\shx
    to[open,v^=$V_{I_{2}}$,o-o,color=red]++\unyn
        node[ground] {} %{GND}
;

\end{circuitikz}%
}}
\caption{Photo Diode Circuit as of Mar 26,16}\label{DiodeC}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

However, it is vital to check the output visually when you do this as TeX will issue no warning if the content of the circuit goes off the edge of the paper! (After all, you've assured it that the content is `0pt` wide, so it cannot possibly spill off the edge!)

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank-you! A little change I made after your fix was to re-scale it to 0.65 and to use \documentclass[landscape]{article} instead( but that's just aesthetics)

Comment: You can also use `lscape` or `pdflscape` and then use the `landscape` environment. Or `rotating` which gives you the `sidewaysfigure` environment. If you don't want the whole thing in landscape.